# not able to install Unity tweak in Ubuntu 12.04: 404 Not Found error

Tags: unity, apt

While installing Unity tweak, I am getting following error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: That PPA doesn't support Precise.. It supports Quantal, Raring and Saucy..

Comment: It is not for your distribution. But what do you want to change? Most of the things you can do with Ubuntu Tweak can be done with the terminal, too.